# ¿Por qué decimos "por hache o por be"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado, historia, españa

Según el diccionario:

> **[por hache o por be](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jws4qSR)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Por una u otra causa.

Siempre me ha resultado curiosa esta expresión, ya que me da la sensación de que la *hache* y la *be* hacen referencia a alguna otra palabra o expresión, tal vez una expresión latina cuyas iniciales fueran esas y hoy día solo la referenciáramos a través de dichas iniciales. Aunque la verdad es que la expresión parece reciente, esto es lo más antiguo que encuentro en el CORDE:

> *¡De manera que a ver si hay un poquito de formalidad, que ya llevan dos veces que se les llama la atención por hache o por be, y estoy viendo que todavía me van a poner ustedes en el trámite de avisar a mi marido!*
>
> Rafael Sánchez Ferlosio, "El Jarama", 1956 (España).

De hecho, la primera aparición de esta expresión en el diccionario fue en 1984 en el *Academia manual*, y redirige a la expresión *por ce o por be*. Esta nueva expresión se recoge en el diccionario desde 1817 en el DLE con una pequeña diferencia en el significado: "de un modo u otro". Y cita como ejemplo: "Por ce ó por be se salió con la suya". Nótese que no es lo mismo "de un modo u otro" que "por un motivo u otro", aunque el diccionario actual recoge las dos expresiones [como sinónimas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=848jnqM) (ante lo cual discrepo: en la cita de arriba yo podría sustituir *por hache o por be* por *por un motivo u otro*, pero no por *de un modo u otro*). Curiosamente no logro encontrar en el CORDE ningún ejemplo de esta versión de la expresión.

Así pues, ¿significan algo esa *ce* y esa *be* de la expresión original? ¿O fue solo una expresión inventada así sin más? ¿Cómo evolucionó la *ce* a la actual *hache*? ¿Cuándo y cómo tuvo lugar ese cambio de matiz en el significado?

Comment: Es desconocido en Chile. Acá decimos _por angas o por mangas_ tanto para "de un modo u otro" como para "por un motivo u otro".

Comment: @Rodrigo le pongo entonces el tag [tag:españa]. Si alguien ve que se usa en otro sitio, puede quitar la etiqueta.

Comment: Seguramente debe su existencia al hecho de que en algunas tipografías cursiva y góticas, la hache y la be se parecen mucho.

Comment: Específica de España no es; la usamos también en Argentina.

Answer (score 6):

En [este enlace](https://comaconcomilla.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/de-donde-viene-la-expresion-por-hache-o-por-be/) hay tres posibles orígenes o teorías:

1. Una discusión acerca de cómo se escribe "uva" (te puedes equivocar, por la hache, o por la be).
2. Motivo de suspensos en ortografía (por hache o por be)...
3. La expresión bien puede venir de las formulas matemáticas relacionadas con los triángulos, donde "B" es la base y "H" la altura. Ver por ejemplo [Área de un triángulo](http://www.universoformulas.com/matematicas/geometria/area-triangulo-base-altura-conocida/). Al parecer durante varias generaciones los libros de matemáticas tenían origen francés y se escribía "h x b" (hauteur par base), y no "a x b" (altura por base), de ahí que aún hoy conservemos dicha fórmula usando la letra H para la "Altura" y no la letra A. Esto se apunta por Javier del Hoyo en su libro "Etimologicón" (Ariel, 2013).

Por mi parte añado, citando del enlace nº 1: "Dependiendo del tipo de triángulo puedes necesitar un elemento (triángulo equilátero), dos (base y altura) o tres (siempre que no sean los tres ángulos)".

Comment: Gran respuesta, pero no me resisto a decir que h×b no es de un triángulo, porque le falta el "partido por dos" ^^

Answer (score 6):

Hay una selección de frases similares:

- [decir] cesta por ballesta ([1605](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=110518%5C011%5CC000O11052018110621640.1212.1208&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+cesta+por+ballesta%7B%7CI%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B%7CI%7D+%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), [1616](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2_NiAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PT198&lpg=RA1-PT198&dq=%22cesta+por+ballesta%22))
- por zancas o por barrancas ([1770](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HVFSDMIeLI4C&pg=PA450&dq=zancas+barrancas))
- per fas et nafas ([cc 1200](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kPhJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&dq=%22per+fas+et+nefas%22) `It`)

  - por fas o por nefas ([cc 1518](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=110518%5C011%5CC003O11052018114213875.1204.1200&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+fas+DIST/5+nefas%7B%7CI%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B%7CI%7D+%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), [1553](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/por-fas-o-por-nef%C3%A1s.1612396/))
- a por a, y be por be ([1611](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YsRKAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA3-PA204&dq=%22be+por+be%22), [1674](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U4FXAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA140-IA1&dq=%22be+por+be%22))

  - por a, be o ce ([1982](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0jZ5AAAAMAAJ&q=%22por+a,+be+o+ce%22))
  - ce por ce, y be por be ([1663](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IbZdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA200&dq=%22ce+por+ce%22))

    - ce por be ([1561](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=110518%5C011%5CC003O11052018110200781.1204.1200&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+%27ce+por+be%27%7B%7CI%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B%7CI%7D+%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), [1773](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=G8hQAAAAcAAJ&q=%22ce+por+be%22&dq=%22ce+por+be%22)) (*Con lujo de detalles*)
    - be por be ([1809](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dUEPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22be+por+be%22))
    - por che o por be ([1941](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=110518%5C011%5CC003O11052018110408344.1204.1200&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+%27o+por+be%27%7B%7CI%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B%7CI%7D+%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0))
    - **por ce o por be** ([1817](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Yx7ZfsfvoMkC&pg=PA191&dq=%22por+ce+o+por+be%22))

      - por ces o por bes ([1927](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_QkMAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Contar,+llamar+ce+por%22+%22por+ees+o+por+bes%22))
      - por hache o por zeta ([1926](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tEAtAQAAMAAJ&q=%22por+hache+o+por+zeta%22))
      - **por hache o por be** ([1965](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SzwNAAAAIAAJ&q=%22hache+o+por+be%22), [1965](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1AYrAAAAIAAJ&q=%22hache+o+por+be%22), [1976](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nqAwAAAAYAAJ&q=%22por+hache%22))
      - por hache o por ce
      - por hache o por erre ([1880](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z7c_AAAAMAAJ&q=por+hache&dq=por+hache))

        - por haches o por erres ([1920](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lQ0LAQAAIAAJ&q=%22por+haches+o+por+erres%22))
        - no decir haches ni erres ([1886](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MpwyAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22haches+ni+erres%22))

> || Fras. Fam. *Por ce ó por be*; de un modo ó de otro, por fas ó por nefas, por zancas ó por barrancas, de todos modos, etc., en cuyo sentido se dice: *por ce ó por be, ya salí con la mía.*

> [*Diccionario nacional o gran diccionario clasico de la lengua ..., Volume 1*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RMdLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA364&dq=%22por+ce+o+por+be%22) (1848)

Parece que, con el tiempo, y por la influencia de la forma de ciertas frases y las significaciones de otras, ha pasado de *'ce por be'* por *'por ce o por be'* hasta *'por hache o por be'* con su definición actual.

Esta cita puede ser de interés:

> **2.3 Idiomaticidad**

> <sup>La idiomaticidad ha sido entendida de dos maneras diferentes. Por un lado, responde, en el sentido etimológico, a lo que es propio y peculiar de una lengua y, por otro, se puede interpretar como el rasgo semántico característico de ciertas construcciones fijas, en las que su significado no puede ser deducido a partir de los elementos que la forman, y así es como debe entenderse en el ámbito fraseolágico. Sentencia Zuluaga (1980: 123-124) que "la expresión idiomática es un signo complejo pero no. simultáneamente y desde el punto de vista funcional, un complejo de signos. Los componentes de esta no se comportan en ella como signos lingüísticos, propiamente. sino. mas bien, como componentes formales de un signo".</sup>

> <sup>Por otro lado, **la idiomaticidad de una unidad pluriverbal no está directamente relacionada con la cantidad de elementos idiomáticos que posea, pues si solo uno funciona idiomáticamente la unidad será idiomática.** En este sentido, se considera que una palabra es idiomática cuando, por pertenecer a etapas sincrónicas previas a la actual de una lengua determinada, tiene valor únicamente dentro de la unidad fraseológica correspondiente, careciendo, por tanto, de vida léxica fuera de ella. **Igualmente, se consideran idiomaticos** los prestamos léxicos, así como **las deformaciones fónicas, morfológicas, apócopes, pues en el seno de una expresión determinan su sentido idiomático** (García-Page Sanchez, 1990: 279-290). **Reflejo de ello son expresiones como *mondo y lirondo, a la Chita callando, sin ton ni son, por fas o por nefás*, etc.**</sup>

> <sup>Pese a que la idiomaticidad se ha tratado habitualmente como uno de los rasgos mas esenciales de las unidades fraseológicas, hay que tener presente que no todas ellas son idiomáticas, pues, mas Bien. «se trata de una característica potencial, no esencial. de este tipo de unidades» (Corpas Pastor, 1996: 27).</sup>

> - [*Las colocaciones y la fraseología*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rjZ3jpoc2sUC&pg=PA8&dq=%22por+fas+o+por+nef%C3%A1s%22)

---

- [***Hablar bien no cuesta tanto:** dudas, etimologías y curiosidades de la lengua española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=Tl0qAQAAIAAJ) (p335-336)
- [*La configuración de las letras como mensaje propio*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7f67AAAAIAAJ), Yakov Malkiel
- [*Eutrapelias del alfabeto español*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XpkdAQAAIAAJ), Jacques de Bruyne (p36)
- [*Revista de la filología española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_QkMAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Contar,+llamar+ce+por%22+%22por+ees+o+por+bes%22), Vol. 14 (1927)

Answer (score 1):

El idioma español es altamente fonético de modo que la ortografía de una palabra se deriva directamente de su fonética. Las (casi) únicas excepciones son la letra H (que es muda en casi todos los casos) y las letras B/V que tienen el mismo sonido. Por ello, para los niños y los estudiantes de español son estas dos letras la principal dificultad en la escritura. Y así, en las redacciones escolares resultaba que "por H o por B" te suspendían el trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

Siendo una expresión idiomática, seguramente su origen es muy dificilmente (si acaso) rastreable.

La explicación más razonable que encuentro es la que se obtiene de la comprensión directa; por ejemplo para aludir a hechos cuyo razón causal resulta indiferente.

> [sea] "*por hache o por be*" has estado llegando tarde de manera repetida.

> "*Por hache o por be*", el propietario no se responsabiliza aún de los arreglos solicitados

Su uso es equivalente a la forma "por ce o por be", originado en los yerros ortográficos que amenazan la escritura de  palabras, a las que en apariencia tanto corresponderían "c" o "s",   como "v" o "b", [sin que eso se refleje fonéticamente en la pronunciacíón para la mayoría de los hispano-hablantes](http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/duda-resuelta-pronunciacion-de-b-y-v/)

La explicación del predominio —o preferencia— de la expresión que citas (hache por be) probablemente se deba al mayor contraste sonóro; las dos expresiones significan lo mismo, pero ésta última suena más nítida y distinguible al oido.

En relación a su semántica, coincido en que se usa para denotar el sentido de "**por una u otra razón**", y no "*de uno u otro modo*" como el diccionario (a mi parecer también), incorrectamente refiere como sinónimos.